# Ansible: Bad configuration option: pubkeyacceptedalgorithms

Tags: ssh, ansible

I'm running ansible core v2.12.5 via Docker with Python 3.10.4.

In my host Ubuntu 22.04 `ssh/config` I have these entries:

```sh
Host git-codecommit.*.amazonaws.com
  User AP-----------------
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
  IdentitiesOnly yes
  PubkeyAcceptedAlgorithms +ssh-rsa
  HostkeyAlgorithms +ssh-rsa

Host 172.x.y.z
  IdentitiesOnly yes
  PubkeyAcceptedAlgorithms +ssh-rsa
  HostkeyAlgorithms +ssh-rsa
```

Because that two hosts need that `ssh-rsa`.

Now, I'm tryng to run Ansible from my Ubuntu 22.04 to perform some task to another Ubuntu 22.04.

I get this error in console:

```sh
TASK [Gathering Facts] ******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [192.168.1.42]: UNREACHABLE! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: /root/.ssh/config: line 5: Bad configuration option: pubkeyacceptedalgorithms\r\n/root/.ssh/config: line 10: Bad configuration option: pubkeyacceptedalgorithms\r\n/root/.ssh/config: terminating, 2 bad configuration options", "unreachable": true}
```

Cannot understand why `ansible` looks at that options if host to setup is totally different.

Comment: It's almost certainly that your ssh is too old, since (for comparison) [22.04's man page mentions it](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/en/man5/ssh_config.5.html) but [20.04's does not](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/en/man5/ssh_config.5.html). If you're asking "why does ssh parse **all** my config file for correctness" then we can't help you

Comment: Thank you to had put me in right direction. I'm updating SSH version on my Docker image.